# PHP 5.3.3 configuration modules

Tags: php, centos

I have a server running Centos 6.4 32 bits with PHP 5.3.3 and so far so good, I installed PHP using yum. I notice that when calling the function phpinfo() I get the following output:

> './configure' '--build=i386-redhat-linux-gnu'
>   '--host=i386-redhat-linux-gnu' '--target=i686-redhat-linux-gnu'
>   '--program-prefix=' '--prefix=/usr' '--exec-prefix=/usr'
>   '--bindir=/usr/bin' '--sbindir=/usr/sbin' '--sysconfdir=/etc'
>   '--datadir=/usr/share' '--includedir=/usr/include' '--libdir=/usr/lib'
>   '--libexecdir=/usr/libexec' '--localstatedir=/var'
>   '--sharedstatedir=/var/lib' '--mandir=/usr/share/man'
>   '--infodir=/usr/share/info' '--cache-file=../config.cache'
>   '--with-libdir=lib' '--with-config-file-path=/etc'
>   '--with-config-file-scan-dir=/etc/php.d' '--disable-debug'
>   '--with-pic' '--disable-rpath' '--without-pear' '--with-bz2'
>   '--with-exec-dir=/usr/bin' '--with-freetype-dir=/usr'
>   '--with-png-dir=/usr' '--with-xpm-dir=/usr' '--enable-gd-native-ttf'
>   '--without-gdbm' '--with-gettext' '--with-gmp' '--with-iconv'
>   '--with-jpeg-dir=/usr' '--with-openssl' '--with-pcre-regex=/usr'
>   '--with-zlib' '--with-layout=GNU' '--enable-exif' '--enable-ftp'
>   '--enable-magic-quotes' '--enable-sockets' '--enable-sysvsem'
>   '--enable-sysvshm' '--enable-sysvmsg' '--with-kerberos'
>   '--enable-ucd-snmp-hack' '--enable-shmop' '--enable-calendar'
>   '--without-sqlite' '--with-libxml-dir=/usr' '--enable-xml'
>   '--with-system-tzdata' '--with-apxs2=/usr/sbin/apxs' '--without-mysql'

The following are all disabled

> '--without-gd' '--disable-dom' '--disable-dba' '--without-unixODBC'
>   '--disable-pdo' '--disable-xmlreader' '--disable-xmlwriter'
>   '--without-sqlite3' '--disable-phar' '--disable-fileinfo'
>   '--disable-json' '--without-pspell' '--disable-wddx' '--without-curl'
>   '--disable-posix' '--disable-sysvmsg' '--disable-sysvshm'
>   '--disable-sysvsem'

I have all the other INI been parsed:

> /etc/php.d/curl.ini, /etc/php.d/fileinfo.ini, /etc/php.d/gd.ini,
>   /etc/php.d/json.ini, /etc/php.d/mbstring.ini, /etc/php.d/mssql.ini,
>   /etc/php.d/mysql.ini, /etc/php.d/mysqli.ini, /etc/php.d/odbc.ini,
>   /etc/php.d/pdo.ini, /etc/php.d/pdo_dblib.ini,
>   /etc/php.d/pdo_mysql.ini, /etc/php.d/pdo_odbc.ini,
>   /etc/php.d/pdo_sqlite.ini, /etc/php.d/phar.ini, /etc/php.d/soap.ini,
>   /etc/php.d/sqlite3.ini, /etc/php.d/zip.ini

And in all of them the module is enabled.

Is that how it is suppose to look or am I missing something?

Comment: Why a negative vote? this is a valid question

Comment: What exactly is the problem?

Comment: That I have the modules installed, but in the configuration section they seem (the modules) not enabled

Comment: He just want to clarify if his installation has valid configuration or not. The question was helpful for me. No sense marking it for -1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. The PHP module *itself* is built *without* all those extensions, and then the extensions are built *separately* and the base PHP module loads them *dynamically*. Move along, nothing to see.

Comment: So, the concept is that even if I see '--disable-pdo', the PDO extension is enabled dynamically, right?

Comment: Can you take a look to this question then: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17496915/pdo-dblib-accessing-sql-server-2008-and-2012

Comment: At the end of the day my issue was not a PHP configuration, but it was good to learn about the change on the PHP setup, the problem was SELinux blocking the connections to the DB server.