# php can't connect to sql server 2008 (using pdo dblib)

Tags: php, sql-server, pdo

I have a SQL server 2008 R2 (running on Windows server 2008 64bit), which I'm trying to connect from PHP

My PHP server configuration:

CentOS 6.6

PHP 5.5.24 (compiled --with-mssql=/usr/local/freetds --with-pdo-dblib=/usr/local/freetds)

Apache 2.4.12

SELinux is disabled (according to this solution: [PDO DBLIB accessing SQL Server 2008 and 2012](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17496915/pdo-dblib-accessing-sql-server-2008-and-2012))

I wrote the following PHP code to connect to the SQL server:

```
try {
    require "classes/mypdo.class.php";
    $pdo = new MyPDO('dblib:dbname=myDB;host=myServer', 'myUser', 'myPassword');
    $pdo->debug = true;
} catch (PDOException $e) {
    die("Connection failed: {$e->getMessage()}");
}
```

The connection failed with an error:

```
Connection failed: SQLSTATE[HY000] Unknown host machine name (severity 2)
```

I tried other DSN syntaxes like:

```
$pdo = new MyPDO('dblib:host=192.168.0.10', 'myUser', 'myPassword');
$pdo = new MyPDO('dblib:host=192.168.0.10:1433', 'myUser', 'myPassword');
$pdo = new MyPDO('dblib:host=myServer', 'myUser', 'myPassword');
```

and many other variations...
When I use an IP address instead of DSN the error is:

```
Connection failed: SQLSTATE[HY000] Unable to connect: Adaptive Server is unavailable or does not exist (severity 9)
```

/etc/freetds.conf

```
[global]
tds version = 7.1
dump file = /tmp/freetds.log
timeout = 10
connect timeout = 10
text size = 64512
client charset = UTF-8

[myServer]
host = 192.168.0.10
port = 1433
tds version = 7.1
```

I suspect that PHP ignoring freetds.conf (can't confirm it).

When I use tsql the connection is working.

```
tsql -S myServer -U MyUser -P MyPassword
locale is "en_US.UTF-8"
locale charset is "UTF-8"
using default charset "UTF-8"
1>
```

What is the reason that PHP refusing to connect to the SQL server?

Answer (score 0):

There are sometimes problems with an setting inside **php.ini**

Please try to change:

```
mssql.secure_connection = Off
```

to

```
mssql.secure_connection = On
```